# Elastic Beanstalk Django deployment, psycopg2 not loading

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Django website to Elastic Beanstalk but I consistently get a 500 error.  I am using Python 3.5 on my system, but Elastic Beanstalk only lets you select 3.4 or 3.6 so I picked 3.4, not sure if that's part of the issue.  Also I SSH'ed in to my EC2 and did "sudo pip install psycopg2" but that did not work either.

Here is a snippet of my error messages.  It always states that psycopg2 is not loading and that WSGI cannot be loaded as target module.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
mod_wsgi (pid=3251): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/omnibus/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=3251): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/omnibus/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python/current/app/omnibus/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
```

Here is my python.config:

```
--------------
python.config
--------------
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "omnibus.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "./omnibus"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "omnibus/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"

packages:
  yum:
   postgresql95-devel: []

container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "python manage.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Here is a snippet from my settings.py:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'omnibus.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

Somebody please help me get my website deployed!!  I will forever be indebted to you!

Comment: Also, this is in my requirements.txt:
psycopg2==2.7.5

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I need more information.  Is there a basic web app example that you started your project with?  Somewhere that has Django working with psychopg2 and postgres?  One thing I noticed you want to do is SSH in and install psychopg2.  Ideally with EB, you want to install everything on your development machine and install to EB via the EB Command line interface (eb cli).  It is much simpler than sshing in.  I can help you do this if you can help me get a working simple example of the web app framework you started with.  Was it a book, blog, dev paltform, etc?  Thanks.